# Scheduling the job based on cron expression

Tags: cron, airflow

I have a requirement to schedule the Airflow job at below schedule.

4:20 AM
10:05 AM
12:05 PM
03:05 PM
6:20 PM
08:05 PM

I could create a separate cron expression for in this format.
0 20 4,18 ? * * * and 0 5 10,12,15,20 ? * * *.

I am not able to combine these two cron expressions or not able to create a single cron expression with above schedule.

Could you guide me how can we trigger the airflow job with above schedule using cron expression?

I couldn't create a single cron expression for in this format.
0 20 4,18 ? * * * and 0 5 10,12,15,20 ? * * *.

Comment: I have never used them, but maybe what you want is doable using [the Timetable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/timetable.html) feature?